# How to use Monogame GraphicsDeviceManager in different class?

Tags: c#, monogame

I have a class which has a method to draw a shape on screen.

```
public class Rectangle : Game1 {

    Texture2D quadl;

    public Rectangle() {    

    }

    public void size() {

        quadl = new Texture2D(this.GraphicsDevice, 100, 100);

    }    
}
```

I then call this in Game1 class update method

`Rectangle rt = new Rectangle();
rt.size();`

it then produces an infinite loop.

What's the problem? and how would I go around fixing it?
i suspect it has something to do with the GraphicsDeviceManager, however I haven't found any help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Rectangle should not inherit from Game1. If you need to access your GraphicsDevice, pass it as an argument to your constructor. Because right now, you are creating a new Game1 for each rectangle.

```
public class Rectangle {

    Texture2D quadl;
    private readonly GraphicsDevice _graphicsDevice;

    public Rectangle(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice) {    
        this._graphicsDevice = graphicsDevice;
    }

    public void size() {
        quadl = new Texture2D(this._graphicsDevice, 100, 100);
    }    
}
```

Because we what you are doing right now, you are creating a new instance of your game with each Rectangle, which will each have their own instance of the GraphicsDevice.